# change of variables in group integral

Tags: group-theory, path-integral, integration, partition-function

When struggling with a difficult integral, one may solve it by simplifying the integral using a change of variables using the corresponding Jacobian determinant.

The typical example being:

$$\int_{\phi(S)} f(v) \mathrm{d}v = \int_{S} f(\phi(S)) \ |\mathrm{det} \ D(\phi)(S)| \ \mathrm{d}S$$

Can we use this trick in integrals over a field, using a different parametrization of the field, and changing the variables by taking the Jacobian of the new parametrization?

Let us say that we have a field $U \in SU(2)$ and we choose to parametrize it by a 2x2 matrix involving some trigonometric functions involving some new variables s,t,r,$\theta$. I have made a simple example down below.

$$\int_{U \ \in \ U(2)} e^{U} \mathrm{d}U = \int_{U(2)} |\mathrm{det} \ J(s,t,r,\theta)| \ e^{str\theta} \mathrm{d}s \ \mathrm{d}t \ \mathrm{d}r \ \mathrm{d}\theta$$

Is this allowed? If not, how can we do something similar?

Comment: See [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure).

Comment: I have looked at Haar measures, and i can see it mentioned in various papers. Personally I can not understand it well enough to answer my own question. Maybe someone in here can help clarify?

Comment: What "field" are you talking about?  Algebraic field (v.g. real or complex)?  Moreover, if $U$ is a group element, are you sure you want $e^U$?  Finally, is $tr$ in your exponential the trace of an element or some product of parameters?

Comment: The field is complex, and yes there is a trace in the exponential. I was just trying to keep everything simple, but i guess it was way too simple. We have $e^{\mathcal{L}_{eff}}=e^{\mathrm{Tr}(D_{\mu}U D^{\mu}U^{\dagger})}$ with $D_{\mu}$ being the covariant derivative. So it is an effective Lagrangian in the exponent with complex fields in U(2).

Comment: To make it clear i do not mean an algebraic field, but a field in the sense of e.g. quark fields in particle physics or scalar fields in quantum field theory.